# Unable to commit to Github, getting commit didn't pass EasyCLA test

Tags: git, github

While committing to a GitHub repo, I'm getting it blocked saying it didn't pass EasyCLA test. Does anyone know how to solve this? Will I need to recommit?

Comment: It is not passing the tests, so check what is wrong with your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Contributor License Agreement(CLA).
Check https://easycla.lfx.linuxfoundation.org/#/

Why you're unable to commit is probably because you didn't include your email and/or user ID amongst other guidelines imposed upon by the maintainers while committing.

Use the following commands to tell Git who's committing :

```
git config --global user.email  "Your email"
```

```
git config --global user.name  "Your user-name"
```

Use these commands before adding your files to Git and make sure you follow other guidelines as well, read the project's documentation.

And yes, you'd need to delete this commit and create a new PR.

Comment: Yes, I had missed these, thanks, it worked, I had to recommit though. Thanks a lot!